# Change an element on mouse click on an image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the paragraph element with `className="details"` to an input field(editable) when user clicks on `className="edit-icon"` image within same grid container. How could I do that ?

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const Settings = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <p className="details-label">NAME</p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <p className="details">Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <img className="edit-icon" src="icon_edit.png"/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <p className="details-label">Phone</p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <p className="details">+123456789</p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <img className="edit-icon" src="icon_edit.png"/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you first post your entire component?

Comment: I've already posted the required part of the code.

Comment: Not really - you are asking how to change part of your container to an input field. There are number of ways to do it. I can write the code - but it will be different if you are using a function component or a class component. That's why I'm asking for your entire component.

the solution - add an onclick handler on the edit-icon img that will change the state of your component to "editable"
add a condition to the element you want to change - if it's editable, render an input, if not, render your details.

Comment: Okay, I've added the entire component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution:
If you want each container to be editable on click independently, I would separate the code into multiple components:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const Container = ({ attr, val }) => {
  const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState(false)
  return (
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <p className="details-label">{attr}</p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          {isEditable ? <input type="text" defaultValue={val} /> : <p className="details">{val}</p>}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <img onClick={() => setIsEditable(!isEditable)} className="edit-icon" 
  src="icon_edit.png"/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
  )
  
}

const Settings = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Settings</p>
      <Container attr="NAME" val="John Doe" />
      <Container attr="Phone" val="+123456789"/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Comment: I have edited your answer as it's giving an error saying `toggleEditable is not defined`

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. I hope you liked my question too.

Comment: What could we do if we want to give input element different name for every Container ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question - we already passing the name as a prop - attr="NAME"

Comment: I meant to say that if we want to assign input element a particular name like <input name="phone" /> then how to access that? As I have tried assigning the different names but not able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do this declaratively now that you're using React.

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-hill-6u1s8?file=/src/App.js) if you want to play around.

Also note you must set your `defaultValue` to the same `p` value, for better UX. It works well for multiple grid containers.

```
import React from 'react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const Settings = () => {

  const [editable, setEditable] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <p className="details-label">NAME</p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          { editable ? <input type="text" defaultValue="Lorem Ipsum"> : 
          <p className="details">Lorem Ipsum</p> }
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <img className="edit-icon" src="icon_edit.png"/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <p className="details-label">Phone</p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          { editable ? <input type="text" defaultValue="+123456789"> : 
          <p className="details">Lorem Ipsum</p> }
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <img className="edit-icon" src="icon_edit.png"/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Comment: Useful, but I want to edit them individually them. Still I liked your answer and giving upvote. I hope you liked my question too.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of [Pranav Rustagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14046126/pranav-rustagi)'s answer, it can be edited to keep the content of the paragraph, by passing it as the `value` attribute of the input element.

```js
var imageCollection = document.querySelectorAll("[className='edit-icon']");
for (var i = 0; i < imageCollection.length; i++) {
  imageCollection[i].onclick = function() {
    let parent = this.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
    let paragraphValue = parent.children[0].innerHTML;
    parent.innerHTML = '';

    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = paragraphValue;
    parent.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <p className="details-label">NAME</p>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <p className="details">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <img className="edit-icon" src="icon_edit.png"/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <p className="details-label">Phone</p>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <p className="details">+123456789</p>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <img className="edit-icon" src="icon_edit.png"/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at my latest code. This code would make all of them editable at once. But I want to make only the one editable.

Comment: It didn't for me, instead it only applied the event listener to the first edit-icon in the document. I have modified it, so it iterates through all such elements. Notice the use of querySelectorAll() instead of querySelector().

Comment: Could you please tell how to implement this in react ?